# Handling FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException when using FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, facebook-authentication

I am currently using Firebase-UI for Android to implement authentication flow in my app. I currently have Google, Facebook, and Email auth providers enabled. My Android app is built using Jetpack Compose and I'm using *rememberLauncherForActivityResult* to launch the login intent. Everything is working as expected with the normal flow.

However, when I try to use my Facebook login with the same email that I have previously authenticated using Gmail, I am getting the below error.

> A sign-in error occurred.
> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: This credential is already associated with a different user account.**
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzxc.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:4)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzya.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:7)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyb.zzl(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzxy.zzq(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:3)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzxy.zze(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzxa.zze(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvf.zzd(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:8)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuf.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:2)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyj.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:12)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:14)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzxp.zzq(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:4)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzug.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:4)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvf.zzM(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:5)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvf.zzs(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:4)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzxb.zzm(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:6)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvr.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyc.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.1.0:1)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

I would like someway to handle this exception but I am not able to find a way. Am I missing something obvious?

Here is my implementation

*ProfileViewModel.kt*

```
override fun buildLoginIntent(): Intent {

    val authUILayout = AuthMethodPickerLayout.Builder(R.layout.auth_ui)
        .setGoogleButtonId(R.id.btn_gmail)
        .setEmailButtonId(R.id.btn_email)
        .setFacebookButtonId(R.id.btn_facebook)
        .build()


    val googleScopes = arrayListOf(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
    )

    val intent = AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setAvailableProviders(
            listOf(
                AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().setScopes(googleScopes).build(),
                AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build()
            )
        )
        .enableAnonymousUsersAutoUpgrade()
        .setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(authUILayout)
        .build()


    return intent
}


@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
override fun onLoginResult(result: FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult) {

// Handle result

}
```

*ProfileUI.kt*

Composable UI where I launch the intent

```
val loginLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    profileViewModel.buildLoginActivityResult()
) { result ->

    if (result != null) {
        profileViewModel.onLoginResult(result = result)
    }
}

if (isAnonymousUser) {
    SignInUI() {
            loginLauncher.launch(profileViewModel.buildLoginIntent())
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from my answer, if you don't want to use the Firebase-UI library, and if you want to manage the authentication process yourself, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: I also think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will also help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I try to use my Facebook login with the same email that I have previously authenticated using Gmail, I am getting the below error.

> This credential is already associated with a different user account.

That's the expected behavior since your user was first time authenticated with Google. When you authenticate a user in Firebase with Google, there is a user created that contains the data that corresponds to that particular provider. If you try to use that data to authenticate to Facebook, the authentication will fail, because the user was already created with another provider, hence the error.

A solution for this kind of situation would be to check if the user already exists, before authenticating it. If the user already exists, then you have to read the provider and display a message to the user, so it can choose the right authentication provider.

Another option might be to allow the creation of different accounts for different providers. You can find this option which is called "Create multiple accounts for each identity provider" right inside the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), in the Settings tab inside the Authentication.

Comment: Hey Babloo. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?